# Highcharts, have all but first series turned off on chart load

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I have a highcharts chart with many series. It is an unreadable mess with all the series showing. Is there a way to have the chart load with all but the first one turned off such that they can be toggled on/off as required?

Comment: [Check this out](http://highcharts.uservoice.com/forums/55896-general/suggestions/1930745-allow-disabling-series-by-default), which links to [this demo](http://jsfiddle.net/highcharts/ACKmb/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `visible: false` to the series you want to hide. See [here](http://jsfiddle.net/ssarabando/GCqsf/5/).

Answer (score 3):

When adding a series, you can set the default visible state using the [`Visible` property](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#plotOptions.series.visible).

For example:

```
series: [{
    data: [5, 7, 3, 2, 9],
    visible: true
}, {
    data: [2, 0, 5, 3, 8],
    visible: false
}]
```

This example will show only the first series by default.

[Here is a demo](http://jsfiddle.net/highcharts/ACKmb/) that I found on the Highcharts site